# How to enable verbose logging from Android Studio to run for example adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, command-line, adb

I was reading "Mastering Firebase for Android Development", by Ashok Kumar S, published by Packt Publishing, 2018. The book has a section called "Firebase Analytics for Android". I followed all the steps from that section and now I only need to check if my implementation was successful. The book explains how to do it:

> We can check whether events are being logged by enabling verbose logging, as shown here:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Where in Android Studio can I run those commands? Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

I guess I can run it from the terminal in Android Studio:

[image]

I think I could run it even outside of Android Studio, from the terminal. But where should I navigate to? Maybe to the location where I have `adb` installed? Thank you.

**UPDATE 2:**

I am getting this message: `bash: adb: command not found`. See what I am doing from the terminal that I have access to from Android Studio:

```
Jaimes-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools jaimemontoya$ pwd
/Users/jaimemontoya/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
Jaimes-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools jaimemontoya$ ls
NOTICE.txt                      deployagent.jar                 etc1tool                        make_f2fs                       sload_f2fs
adb                             deploypatchgenerator.jar        fastboot                        mke2fs                          source.properties
api                             dmtracedump                     hprof-conv                      mke2fs.conf                     sqlite3
deployagent                     e2fsdroid                       lib64                           package.xml                     systrace
Jaimes-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools jaimemontoya$ adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
bash: adb: command not found
Jaimes-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools jaimemontoya$
```

Comment: maybe you need add platform-tools to $path or call it this way: ./adb

Comment: @ilya Exactly! That was the solution I applied. I just had forgotten to mention it here to have this question marked as answered. You can answer it so that we have this question closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked whether events were being logged by enabling verbose logging, as shown here:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

For testing purposes, I used the following code in my `InitialActivity.java`:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "InitialActivity");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

Then I went to the command line to execute the `adb` commands to see from the Android Studio debug logs the data that I sent:

```
$ pwd
/Users/jaimemontoya/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
[My MacBook Pro]:platform-tools jaimemontoya$ ./adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

I can see the data that I sent:

```
02-21 11:46:35.585 D/FA      ( 3106): Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle[{item_name=FirstActivity, firebase_event_origin(_o)=app}]
02-21 11:46:36.389 V/FA      ( 6924): Logging event: origin=app,name=select_content,params=Bundle[{item_name=FirstActivity, firebase_event_origin(_o)=app}]
02-21 11:46:36.399 V/FA      ( 6924): Event recorded: Event{appId='com.couponclub', name='select_content', params=Bundle[{item_name=FirstActivity, firebase_event_origin(_o)=app}]}
```